# Set Variable of 'Object' type in ADF possible?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I cannot see any option for creating a variable of type `Object` in the `Set Variable Activity` . of `Azure Data Factory`. Only types that are allowed seem to be `String`, `Boolean` & `Array`. How do I assign a SQL table's data which I'm getting through a `Lookup Activity` to a variable then(which I need for further processing) then? Is there a workaround for this or am I missing something here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Don’t assign it to a variable.  Just reference it in the next activity using dot syntax.  The expression editor will guide you through, you normally need .output on the end or similar.

Comment: @wBob cool, I also tried to use a Filter Activity on the result of my Lookup Activity(returns rows of data from a DB table). Can I actually apply Filter on this object or can it be applied only on Arrays? I used '@activity('GetTableData').output' for specifying 'Items' and '@equals(item().propertyID, 123)' as the Filter Condition but I'm getting 'Bad Request' error. Any idea about this?

Comment: What type of activity is "GetTableData'? .output is usually a JSON object with properties, so you may need to reference a property like @activity('GetTableData').output.value.

Comment: What is it you actually are trying to achieve? If you know in advance you need to filter data, I'd suggest doing so in a WHERE clause so the database will do the filtering for you. What is it you need the filtered data for?

Comment: @SchmitzIT - this is good advice assuming there is a database involved, but many data operations don't involve databases.

Comment: @JoelCochran - He specified using a database in his first reply.

Comment: @SchmitzIT - thanks, I missed that detail.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the Data factory variable can only store values of type `String, Boolean or Array`.

- One possible workaround is to convert the `Object` type to `String` type using **@string()** function. Then use **@json() function** on your variable to convert it back to `Object` type whenever necessary and use it.

Here is a demonstration of the above specified workaround.

- Use `@string(activity('Lookup1').output)` to convert the output of **Lookup Activity** to `String` type and store it in `json_as_string` (**String**) variable.

[image]

- If you now want to use this value anywhere, say *filter activity*, you can simply specify `@json(variables('json_as_string')).value` as **items**.

[image]

- Debug output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes .The output of a adf pipeline activity is in the form of JSON.the output of lookup activity can be saved inside a variable.You need to check the output of the lookup and save it inside variable for your purpose.